# history.back() in experience cloud - Is it possible?

Tags: html, experience-cloud, community-cloud

we are trying to implement a user friendly navigation in our experience cloud. We are trying to build a simple "go back" - Button using the HTML - component in the generator.

What I have so far is this:

```
<form action="history.back()"> <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="background: #ffda00;color: #333333;width: 173.5px;height: 43px;border-style: none; border-radius: 3px;">Go back</button> </form>
```

However all it does is refresh the page I am already on. Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes it's possible, but when combined specifically with forms you run the risk of causing the form to resubmit. This also wouldn't work if the user doesn't have any history to go back to. Would redirecting the user to a specific page be better?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out @nbrown. I ended up implementing a lightning component:

<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<button class="slds-button" onclick="{!c.doYourAction}" > 
   <lightning:icon iconName="utility:chevronleft" size="medium" alternativeText="left" />
</button></aura:component>

({
    doYourAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        var url = window.location.href; 
            var value = url.substr(0,url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            window.history.back();
            return false;
    }
})

Comment: If that's what you did to solve your problem I'd put that in an answer with structured code blocks instead of a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that Experience is a Single Page Application. This means that if you want to go forwards/backwards, you need to update the page's state somehow. For LWC components, use NavigationMixin and CurrentPageReference to update the state of the page, and for Aura, you should be able to use window.history.replaceState to update the URL and/or state of the page, and use the onstatechange handler to react to those changes. If your code conforms to these rules, then history.back() will work as you expect.